# How does CMake add_executable work internally (dependencies and automatic source discovery)?

Tags: c, cmake, compilation

I am working on my first CMake/C project and I crossed a problem with my build that makes me re-question how compilation work.

I would like people to explain to me what exactly happens when you call **add_executable** and how make builds C file dependencies.

## What I thought

I thought that, when calling **add_executable (name, sources)**, CMake would see **sources** as a superset of the necessary source files to build the target name. So internally, he analyzes the REAL MINIMAL dependencies, by analyzing the file containing `main`, and recursively adding the included .h files, with their associated declarations in the .c files.

## What seem to happen (I want confirmation)

CMake sees **sources** as the real minimum dependencies for the executable. It seems it will compile ANYTHING in **sources**, whether or not it is used anywhere.

## Consequence

This for me is really annoying. In my project I use source discovery, meaning that anything in the src directory is added to the sources. Then, if I want to compile a unit test (`make this_unit_test`), it is, in fact, going to compile every .o file in my source directory instead of compiling the necessary files only. Which means that if something does not build in a part of my project, I can not build any tests anymore.

## What can I do?

If CMake is indeed done in a way that you need to specify yourself the minimal dependencies for any executable, how can I still use automatic source/test discovery? The best solution would be from the CMakeList file, a function that takes a list of source files, and return the subset of it corresponding to what is actually included at some point by the file containing `main`. What do people do to resolve that problem?

Comment: *"In my project I use source discovery"* - what does this mean exactly?  Do you mean you use file "globbing" like `*.c` to look for all source files rather than explicitly listing them in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Yes. I know cmake say it's bad. It would not be bad if cmake add a function to do what I want instead of forcing user to manually list each source (I seriously dont understand how people can accept that as a clean solution).  It is probably accepted because parsing source to separate useless stuff for main is harder than it look.

Answer (score 4):

No, CMake does *not* scan for minimal source dependencies for your executable, and how could it? CMake doesn't scan the source files, and has no knowledge about what includes/definitions your executable ultimately needs or doesn't need. This functionality would have to happen at the compilation stage (after CMake completes), because it is the pre-processor/compiler that parses your source files and interprets them for semantics (meaning). There are static analysis tools out there that can help achieve something like this, such as [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/).

Using *source discovery* techniques in CMake (such as [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob)) can be error prone:

1. As you have seen, the source discovery mechanism may grab files that you **do not need** for building a particular target.
2. Even worse, source discovery may **leave out** files that *are* required for building a particular target.

The CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) itself even warns against doing this!

> **Note:** We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

As a general rule of thumb, it is always safest to list each individual file that is required for each target *explicitly*, for example:

```
add_executable(MyExe 
    main.c
    MyHelperFunctions.c
    MyOtherStructs.c
)
```

Comment: Scanning for source file dependencies is complicated for CMake Makefiles.  When using the Makefile generator a Makefile rule is used to run a CMake internal command to scan files that are `Source Files` to generate the depends list.  You can see this being done if you run with `make V=1` and the generate dependencies list.  But, for example, If you use the Ninja generator then the compiler generates the dependencies during compilation. I guess the reason is historically CMake supported very old Make and compilers that didn't handle dependency generation.

Comment: So @fdk1342 , are you saying than if I install ninja and use it as a generator, what I want would work right out of the box?

Comment: I will check the tool you suggested next week squareskittes. Thanks for confirming it work like that, and thanks for the numerous typos edits ;)

Comment: @fdk1342 Thanks for the comments, I did not know about the CMake internal command that runs when using `Unix Makefiles` as the generator. It is still unclear whether this achieves the dependency resolution on the level that the OP was asking, but helpful nonetheless!

Comment: @ninjaconcombre I am not intimately familiar with Ninja, nor many of the other CMake generators, and so I'm not sure what kind of dependency tracking may be provided by the different generators or the compilers themselves. Perhaps, fdk1342 knows more about this. :)  I only know this kind of functionality does not usually occur within CMake.

Comment: The best answer is this one. `add_executable` is used to add all files used for this executable.  If you add stuff that doesn't belong to this executable then that is a mistake as it will compile and link extra files into the executable.  Now, you can put any kind of file in `add_execuable` and CMake will categorize these files.  Depending upon the languages enabled, C and  CXX by default, files ending with `.c` and `.cxx` will be categorized as "Source Files".  `.h` and `.hh` will be categorized as `Header Files`.  Refer to `source_group` command and other IDE related organization settings.

Comment: I don't know of any tool that performs source introspection as requested by OP where you could give it a list of files and it would figure out which files belong to what target.

Comment: The goal is not no figure out what belong to which target @fdk1342, the goal is to follow main function flow to strip files that contain only symbols not used ever by main from a list of file containing one function main.

Comment: Plus it's not always true that useless compiled code end up in executable, as linkers can remove useless code if given appropriates options. I would like a tool that does the same job at the source level so finally source discovery would not be bad practice. Because yes it's cool to separate/add source files code without touching a list of hundreds of files in the Cmake list

Comment: @ninjaconcombre I understand your concerns for wanting to avoid modifying long lists of source files in the CMakeLists.txt. It can be tedious. And yes, I believe some linkers have the capability to leave out unused components. I would check out some of the static analyzers that are available, such as `include-what-you-use`, which may offer the closest thing to what you're looking for.